# Context switch between kernel threads vs user threads

Tags: linux, unix, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel

Copy pasted from [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/operating_system/os_multi_threading) link:

> - Thread switching does not require Kernel mode privileges.
> - User level threads are fast to create and manage.
> - Kernel threads are generally slower to create and manage than the user threads.
> - Transfer of control from one thread to another within the same process requires a mode switch to the Kernel.

I never came across these points while reading standard operating systems reference books. Though these points sound logical, I wanted to know how they reflect in Linux. To be precise :

1. Can someone give detailed steps involved in context switching between user threads and kernel threads, so that I can find the step difference between the two.
2. Can someone explain the difference with actual context switch example or code. May be system calls involved (in case of context switching between kernel threads) and thread library calls involved (in case of context switching between user threads).
3. Can someone link me to Linux source code line (say on github) handling context switch.
4. I also doubt why context switch between kernel threads requires changing to kernel mode. Aren't we already in kernel mode for first thread?

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone give detailed steps involved in context switching between user threads and kernel threads, so that I can find the step difference between the two.

Let's imagine a thread needs to read data from a file, but the file isn't cached in memory and disk drives are slow so the thread has to wait; and for simplicity let's also assume that the kernel is monolithic.

For kernel threading:

- thread calls a "read()" function in a library or something; which must cause at least a switch to kernel code (because it's going to involve device drivers).
- the kernel adds the IO request to the disk driver's "queue of possibly many pending requests"; realizes the thread will need to wait until the request completes, sets the thread to "blocked waiting for IO" and switches to a different thread (that may belong to a completely different process, depending on global thread priorities). The kernel returns to the user-space of whatever thread it switch to.
- later; the disk hardware causes an IRQ which causes a switch back to the IRQ handler in kernel code. The disk driver finishes up the work it had to do the for (currently blocked) thread and unblocks that thread. At this point the kernel might decide to switch to the "now unblocked" thread; and the kernel returns to the user-space of the "now unblocked" thread.

For user threading:

- thread calls a "read()" function in a library or something; which must cause at least a switch to kernel code (because it's going to involve device drivers).
- the kernel adds the IO request to the disk driver's "queue of possibly many pending requests"; realizes the thread will need to wait until the request completes but can't take care of that because some fool decided to make everything worse by doing thread switching in user space, so the kernel returns to user-space with "IO request has been queued" status.
- after the pointless extra overhead of switching back to user-space; the user-space scheduler does the thread switch that the kernel could have done. At this point the user-space scheduler will either tell kernel it has nothing to do and you'll have more pointless extra overhead switching back to kernel; or user-space scheduler will do a thread switch to another thread in the same process (which may be the wrong thread because a thread in a different process is higher priority).
- later; the disk hardware causes an IRQ which causes a switch back to the IRQ handler in kernel code. The disk driver finishes up the work it had to do for the (currently blocked) thread; but the kernel isn't able to do the thread switch to unblock the thread because some fool decided to make everything worse by doing thread switching in user space. Now we've got a problem - how does kernel inform the user-space scheduler that the IO has finished? To solve this (without any "user-space scheduler running zero threads constantly polls kernel" insanity) you have to have some kind of "kernel puts notification of IO completion on some kind of queue and (if the process was idle) wakes the process up" which (on its own) will be more expensive than just doing the thread switch in the kernel. Of course if the process wasn't idle then code in user-space is going to have to poll its notification queue to find out if/when the "notification of IO completion" arrives, and that's going to increase latency and overhead. In any case, after lots of stupid pointless and avoidable overhead; the user-space scheduler can do the thread switch.

> Can someone explain the difference with actual context switch example or code. May be system calls involved (in case of context switching between kernel threads) and thread library calls involved (in case of context switching between user threads).

The actual low-level context switch code typically begins with something like:

- save whichever registers are "caller preserved" according to the calling conventions on the stack
- save the current stack top in some kind of "thread info structure" belonging to the old thread
- load a new stack top from some kind of "thread info structure" belonging to the new thread
- pop whichever registers are "caller preserved" according to the calling conventions
- return

However:

- usually (for modern CPUs) there's a relatively large amount of "SIMD register state" (e.g. for 80x86 with support for AVX-512 I think it's over 4 KiB of of stuff). CPU manufacturers often have mechanisms to avoid saving parts of that state if it wasn't changed, and to (optionally) postpone the loading of (pieces of) that state until its actually used (and avoid it completely if its not actually used). All of that requires kernel.
- if it's a task switch and not just used for thread switches you might need some kind of "if virtual address space needs to change { change virtual address space }" on top of that
- normally you want to keep track of statistics, like how much CPU time a thread has used. This requires some kind of "`thread_info.time_used += now() - time_at_last_thread_switch;`"; which gets difficulty/ugly when "process switching" is separated from "thread switching".
- normally there's other state (e.g. pointer to thread local storage, special registers for performance monitoring and/or debugging, ...) that may need to be saved/loaded during thread switches. Often this state is not directly accessible in user code.
- normally you also want to set a timer to expire when the thread has used too much time; either because you're doing some kind of "time multiplexing" (e.g. round-robin scheduler) or because its a cooperating scheduler where you need to have some kind of "terminate this task after 5 seconds of not responding in case it goes into an infinite loop forever" safe-guard.
- this is just the low level task/thread switching in isolation. There is almost always higher level code to select a task to switch to, handle "thread used too much CPU time", etc.

> Can someone link me to Linux source code line (say on github) handling context switch

Someone probably can't. It's not one line; it's many lines of assembly for each different architecture, plus extra higher-level code (for timers, support routines, the "select a task to switch to" code, for exception handlers to support "lazy SIMD state load", ...); which probably all adds up to something like 10 thousand lines of code spread across 50 files.

> I also doubt why context switch between kernel threads requires changing to kernel mode. Aren't we already in kernel mode for first thread?

Yes; often you're already in kernel code when you find out that a thread switch is needed.

Rarely/sometimes (mostly only due to communication between threads belonging to the same process - e.g. 2 or more threads in the same process trying to acquire the same mutex/semaphore at the same time; or threads sending data to each other and waiting for data from each other to arrive) kernel isn't involved; and in some cases (which are almost always massive design failures - e.g. extreme lock contention problems, failure to use "worker thread pools" to limit the number of threads needed, etc) it's possible for this to be the dominant cause of thread switches, and therefore possible that doing thread switches in user space can be beneficial (e.g. as a work-around for the massive design failures).

Answer (score 1):

Don't limit yourself to Linux or even UNIX, they are neither the first nor last word on systems or programming models.   The synchronous execution model dates back to the early days of computing, and are not particularly well suited to larger scale concurrent and reactive programming.

Golang, for example, employs a great many lightweight user threads -- goroutines -- and multiplexes them on a smaller set of heavyweight kernel threads to produce a more compelling concurrency paradigm.  Some other programming systems take similar approaches.